# Equicontinuity in Peano existence theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I'm having some trouble understanding why the sequence of successive approximations in the proof of the Peano existence theorem is equicontinuous (which is needed to use Arzela-Ascoli theorem):

Here's the theorem and proof as it goes in my textbook (and afterwards I'll lay out the part that I have the problem with):

**Peano's existence theorem:** Let $f:[x_{0},x_{0}+a] \times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then the equation $$y' = f(x,y)$$ has a solution which satisfies the initial condition $y(x_{0})=y_{0}.$

**Proof:** Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_{j}=x_{0}+\frac{aj}{n}$ for $j \in \{0, ..., n\}$. Let $y_{n}:[x_{0}, x_{0}+a] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $y_{n}(x_{0})=y_{0}$ and $$y_{n}'(x) = f(x, y_{n}(x_{j})) \quad \text{for} \quad x_{j}<x\leq x_{j+1},$$

where $y_{n}(x_{j})$ is taken so that $y_{n}$ is continuous. $y_{n}$ satisfies the equation $$y_{n}(x) = y_{0}+ \int_{x_{0}}^{x} y_{n}'(t)dt = y_{0}+\int_{x_{0}}^{x} (f(t, y_{n}(t))+h_{n}(t))dt,$$
where $h_{n}(t)=f(t, y_{n}(x_{j}))-f(t, y_{n}(t))$, where $x_{j}<t\leq x_{j+1}$. Trivially, for large enough $n$, we can approximate $t\in [x_{0}, x_{0}+a]$ as well as we want, and since $y_{n}$ is continuous, we have $||h_{n}||_{\infty} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Since $y_{n}$ is continuous on a compact interval, it's also bounded, so $||y_{n}||_{\infty}<b_{n}$ for some $b_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, from $|y_{n}(u)-y_{n}(v)| \leq \int_{u}^{v} (|f(t, y_{n}(t))|+|h_{n}(t)|)dt<M|u-v|$ for some $M$ (since $f$ is continuous on the compact interval $[x_{0}, x_{0}+a] \times [-b_{n}, b_{n}]$, it reaches its maximum and minimum value, and since $||h_{n}||_{\infty} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, it's also bounded), I'm supposed to deduce a "common Lipschitz constant $M$" for all $y_{n}$, and deduce equicontinuity from there, but $b_{n}$ can go to infinity as $n \to \infty$, and so $M$ depends on $n$.

Is the proof wrong? If so, how can I rectify this error? Or is there something I'm missing? I can't find a more detailed proof of the theorem in any other textbook I've found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Peano existence theorem only guarantees local existence.  Given your conditions we can only conclude that there exists an interval $[x_0,c] \subset [x_0,x_0+a]$ on which a solution exists.

For example, take $[x_0,x_0+a] = [0,2]$ and $f(x,y) = y^2$ which is continuous everywhere. The solution to $y' = y^2$ with $y(0) = 1$ is $y(x) = (1-x)^{-1}$. This blows up at $x = 1$ so the maximal interval of existence is $[0,1)$.

The proof should specify a compact rectangle $R= [x_0, x_0 +a ]\times [y_0 - b, y_0 +b]$ on which $|f(x,y)| \leqslant M$ since $f$ is continuous. With this global bound it is easy to show equicontinuity of the sequence of piecewise linear approximate solutions. It can then be proved that there exists a solution $y$  on some interval $[x_0,c]$ where $c = \min(x_0+a,x_0 + b/M)$ such that $(x,y(x))$ stays inside the rectangle for all $x \in [x_0,c]$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the choice of $b$. Could you elaborate on how it is obtained independent of $n$? Because when I define $y_{n}$, it's not specified how "far from $y_{0}$" it could go.

Comment: It can be any finite positive number.  No matter what we pick we will always find an interval $[x_0,c]$ on which a solution exists. Think about the example. As we take larger and larger $b$ the existence interval extends until it hits a wall at $x=1$. Beyond that the interval extends no further no matter how large we make $b$. In short it is chosen arbitrarily to bound $f$ and prove existence.  Look at the book by Coddington and Levinson.